# wrong thumbnail address

Tags: wordpress

thumbnails of my posts not showing, because that's address is:
/home/…/public_html/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/IMG_0780_wtmkd-49414_207x136.jpg

instead of :
/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/IMG_0780_wtmkd-49414_207x136.jpg

how can solve my problem?

note:
i restore my wordpress website.( that's database exist on server and not deleted)

Comment: how are you adding the code to include an image?

Comment: i use deep fucus theme from elegant themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem!

delete any media in wordpress panel and contents in  uploads folder. then upload my picturs again.

but I began to be curious about this problem's reason and Solution. deleting and uploading can be tedious in a big site with many image